# Call a Perl script with Javascript and display the results

Tags: javascript, ajax, perl, integration

I looked it up on google, but didn't find anything that exactly retained to my question.  Is there anyway to call a Perl script with JavaScript then place what results the Perl script gets into a web doc?  I've read AJAXs can do this, but I was hoping someone could place a simple hello world example that simulates this.  Also, because Perl often has to be installed on a computer before it can be used on it how does javascript even do this? Is it that the server has Perl installed so that when the javascript calls it the server does the computations and then the javascript can grab the results?

Thank You

Comment: The perl script would be running on your server; it can serve the ajax request just like it would any normal request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in the [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us) web framework for Perl, especially since it supports websockets, which are two-way communication between the browser and the server.

[Here is an example](https://github.com/kraih/mojo/blob/master/examples/websocket.pl) of Mojo and websockets. In this example the client sends some text to the server and the server prepends a heart and sends it back for the browser to display. Of course in your case, the server could run some code and send the result back.

This architecture is used heavily in my [Galileo CMS](https://github.com/jberger/Galileo) which uses websockets to update pages without needing a refresh and positive confirmation from the server that the update succeeded.

Comment: This is interesting thanks, I think it's a bit over my head at the moment, but something worth looking into.  Thank you.